# Python Pyinstaller no exe file generated

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I have previously used pyinstaller with a virtual environment but after I got a new computer no .exe file is generated.

I have made a small test file to illustrate the problem

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
import numpy as np

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

test = np.cos(0.5)

messagebox.showinfo("test", test)
```

in CMD i use the following commands to create my file:

```
C:\Users\MRCH> Python -m venv testEnv

C:\Users\MRCH> testEnv\scripts\activate

(testEnv) C:\Users\MRCH> Python -m pip install --upgrade pip

(testEnv) C:\Users\MRCH> pip install numpy

(testEnv) C:\Users\MRCH> pip install pyinstaller

(testEnv) C:\Users\MRCH> pyinstaller test.py -y -F
```

This is the messages I get when I build the file:

```
72 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
73 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
74 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
77 INFO: wrote C:\Users\MRCH\test.spec
78 INFO: UPX is not available.
81 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\MRCH', 'C:\\Users\\MRCH']
82 INFO: checking Analysis
84 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
84 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
88 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
90 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3901 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3905 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\mrch\testenv\scripts\python.exe
3924 INFO: Caching module hooks...
3934 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\MRCH\test.py
4619 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
5830 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
5835 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\mrch\\testenv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
7199 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
10043 INFO: Loading module hooks...
10043 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
10048 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
10367 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
10376 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
10479 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
10482 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
11226 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
11412 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
11596 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
11599 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
12373 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
12377 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
12379 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
12381 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
12419 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
12449 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
12868 INFO: checking Tree
12868 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
12869 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
13002 INFO: checking Tree
13002 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
13003 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
13075 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
13118 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
13125 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
13128 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
13131 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
13144 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
13180 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
13209 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
13239 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
13264 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
13293 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
13322 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
13350 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
13387 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
13418 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
13448 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
13490 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_queue.pyd
13529 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd
13572 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
13602 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
13645 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
13674 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
13701 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
13730 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
13758 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
13794 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
13831 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
13859 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
13898 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_socket.pyd
13941 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
13971 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
13999 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
14037 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
14066 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
14095 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
14123 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
14151 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
14188 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\select.pyd
14225 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win32.pyd
14255 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win32.pyd
14285 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win32.pyd
14315 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp37-win32.pyd
14347 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win32.pyd
14377 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win32.pyd
14405 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win32.pyd
14435 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win32.pyd
14463 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win32.pyd
14492 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win32.pyd
14520 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win32.pyd
14548 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win32.pyd
14585 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win32.pyd
14621 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp37-win32.pyd
14652 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp37-win32.pyd
14681 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.cp37-win32.pyd
14721 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack_lite.cp37-win32.pyd
14750 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack_lite.cp37-win32.pyd
14789 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp37-win32.pyd
14824 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp37-win32.pyd
14856 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp37-win32.pyd
14885 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.cp37-win32.pyd
14929 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.cp37-win32.pyd
14977 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
15008 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
15064 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15094 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15126 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15155 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15184 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15214 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15244 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15276 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15306 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15336 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15363 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15397 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
15433 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\vcruntime140.dll
15462 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\vcruntime140.dll
15491 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\vcruntime140.dll
15520 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\vcruntime140.dll
15548 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\vcruntime140.dll
15615 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
15647 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
15676 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
15706 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
15734 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
15762 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
15790 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
15817 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
15849 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
15880 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
15914 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
15943 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
15974 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
16004 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
16132 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
16173 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
16199 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
16226 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
16255 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
16282 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
16311 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
16341 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
16371 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
16438 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
16466 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
16493 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
16520 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
16552 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
16582 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
16613 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
16644 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
16645 INFO: Looking for eggs
16646 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.dll
16646 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
16660 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\MRCH\build\test\warn-test.txt
16814 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\MRCH\build\test\xref-test.html
16891 INFO: checking PYZ
16891 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
16892 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\MRCH\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz
18341 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\MRCH\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
18368 INFO: checking PKG
18368 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
18370 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\MRCH\testEnv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 32, in <module>
  File "c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 424, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 196, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\mrch\testenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 273, in assemble
    pylib_name = os.path.basename(bindepend.get_python_library_path())
  File "C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 214, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "C:\Users\MRCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

So it would seem I'm missing a ton of libs, but I'm not really sure which?

I have added Python to my windows environment, so it's not that.
[image]

**EDIT** (May 10th, 2019)

I have Python in both my "User variables" and in my "System variables".

After `pip install -U pypiwin32` I still get a huge list of errors. I Can't post it here due to the limitation of characters, but I've uploaded the textfile to my dropbox:
[Python_Message.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqerc1ies6qpg9m/Python_Message.txt?dl=0)

This is my piplist in my virtual environment:

```
(testEnv) C:\Users\MRCH>pip list
Package        Version
-------------- ---------
altgraph       0.16.1
future         0.17.1
macholib       1.11
numpy          1.16.3
pefile         2019.4.18
pip            19.1
PyInstaller    3.4
pypiwin32      223
pywin32        224
pywin32-ctypes 0.2.0
setuptools     40.8.0
```

Comment: Hello can you print out the result of `pip list` in your venv?

Comment: Sure, the pip list has been posted in an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a BUG in bindepend.py replace it from \venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend with the file provided in this page on github:
[Issues](https://github.com/Loran425/pyinstaller/commit/14b6e65642e4b07a4358bab278019a48dedf7460)

Answer (score 2):

try to install pypiwin32

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Comment: Because it's not any different from the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I upgrade pypiwin32 using pip.
Try this

```
pip install -U pypiwin32
```

just make sure your Python package is in the system path.

Comment: Unfortunately, this had little effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same happen to me today, because I did not install as admin `pip install pyinstaller`.

At first it was not clear why it failed. It seemed to install succesfully but without exe generated.
But during debugging when I tried to upgrade pip i got the error
`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\python310\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-22.0.4.dist-info\\entry_points.txt' Consider using the` --user `option or check the permissions.`

It was solved by restarting the command prompt as admin, and running

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
pip install pyinstaller
```